# Determine if a package is provided by an installed packagein Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to script the installation of optional "dependencies" depending on what other packages are installed in an Arch Linux system. I can use `pacman -Q` to tell me if a package has been installed either directly or as a dependency, but this fails if the package is "installed" via [provides](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#provides) in the PKGBUILD. How can I determine if a package that provides a package has been installed? The specific issue I have is I want to install `kile` if both `kdebase-workspace` and `texlive-core` are installed. The issue is that I cannot pick up that the [AUR `texlive-dummy`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-dummy/) package is providing `texlive-core`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [package-query](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/package-query) to search packages by their 'provides' property. E.g.:

```
$ package-query --qprovides 'mplayer=36265' -Q -f "%n"
mplayer-vaapi
```

will list all installed packages that provides 'mplayer=36265'.